# Farseer Physics Engine - Body won't go past certain speed no matter the impulse applied

Tags: c#, xna, physics, farseer

Hello
I'm relatively new to farseer engine, which i'm currently trying to integrate with my own.
I decided to test a few things, saw the samples, but there's is definitely something wrong about what i'm doing, even though I can't see what is wrong.

I just added a `Body` to the `World`, and called `ApplyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(200f,0))`

Then I tried higher numbers, but the speed remained the same. Is there a limit for that ? What is happening ?

I'll give more details if needed, but I'm guessing it's something very noobish I missed.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Objects cannot exceed the speed of light! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value seems way to big for Farseer. Are you using ConvertUnits in your code? Look at [this blog](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2011/02/farseer-physics-engines-meter-kilogram.html).

Comment: Rofl. I used farseer some time ago and I think by that time this "ConvertUnits" thing didn't exist. Thanks for the response!